# autocomplete for dynamically created inputs

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

first post! and a noob in java*whatever!

I know there are many posts regarding this topic, I've read them.. I just can't get it solved.

I have very simple HTML form with statics inputs and dynamically created inputs.

**HTML Autocomplete**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Funcion Autocomplete de jQuery para buscar los clientes y los productos en el input con id "buscar" y clase "buscar_prod"
    $().ready(function() {
        $("#buscar").autocomplete("get_client_list.php", {
            width: 260,
            matchContains: true,
            selectFirst: false
        });
    });
    $().ready(function() {
        $(".buscar_prod").autocomplete("get_product_list.php", {
            width: 260,
            matchContains: true,
            selectFirst: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML Form**

```
<form method="post" action="add_order.php">

 Cliente: <input type="text" name="cliente" id="buscar">

 <div id="dynamicInput">
      Referencia y cantidad <br><input type="text" class="buscar_prod" name="input_referencia[]"><input type="text" name="input_cantidad[]">
 </div>
 <input type="button" value="Adicionar otra referencia" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput','order');">
 <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Guardar" />
```

**addInput.js**

```
var counter = 1;

function addInput(divName,category){
    switch(category){
    case "order":
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = "Referencias y cantidad " + (counter + 1) + " 
";
        document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
        counter++;
        break;

    case "product":
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = "Componente y cantidad " + (counter + 1) + " 
";
        document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
        counter++;
        break;

    case "component":
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = "Proveedor y Precio " + (counter + 1) + " 
";
        document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
        counter++;
        break;
    }
}
```

So question is simple,.. given these codes, how could I implement the autocomplete in each new generated input.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you cannot have elements with the same IDs. you should trigger the events from a class.

Comment: And please avoid `$().ready`, use instead `$(document).ready`

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers! I actually just resolved my problem, i just cannot post the answer for being a new user.

adding 

        $(".buscar_prod").autocomplete("get_product_list.php", {
          width: 260,
          matchContains: true,
          selectFirst: false
      });

after

document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);

got the work done.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach the autocomplete after you have added the element to the DOM, like:

```
$(newdiv).autocomplete("get_client_list.php", {
    width: 260,
    matchContains: true,
    selectFirst: false
});
```

you can call the specific autocomplete code according to your switch-case statement.

Comment: Yes! actually, that did the trick! Just a minute before your answer became vivisble I wanted to post that playing with some more examples I found that adding that code resolved the issue, nevertheless, because of being a new user I cannot posts answers. So, thank you so much for also answering the question!