# jQuery dynamically input fields + autocomplete not working correctly (always firing at first input)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

Ok... thanks to your help, I manage to sort out these issues:

["autocomplete for dynamically created inputs"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862927/autocomplete-for-dynamically-created-inputs)

and

["jQuery dinamically input fields not working"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936670/jquery-dinamically-input-fields-not-working)

Nevertheless, when I try to mix the whole thing up, (dynamic inputs + autocomplete) the thing just won't work :-( right now,.. I cannot get none of them working. Here's the code once again...

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="javascript/jquery.autocomplete.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/jquery.autocomplete.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Funcion Autocomplete de jQuery para buscar los clientes y los productos en el input con clase "buscar" y clase "buscar_prod"
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#buscar").autocomplete("get_client_list.php", {
                width : 260,
                matchContains : true,
                selectFirst : false
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".buscar_prod").autocomplete("get_product_list.php", {
                width : 260,
                matchContains : true,
                selectFirst : false
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
                var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
                $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
                    $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
                });
                $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
                    if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
                        $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
    <title>AQUATAP - Gestor de Información - Añadir Pedido</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form role="form" action="add_order.php" method="POST">
        Cliente:
        <input type="text" name="cliente" id="buscar">
        <br>
        <hr />
        Fecha de salida:
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="salida_pronosticada" value="male">
        En el día
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="salida_pronosticada" value="male">
        2 días
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="salida_pronosticada" value="female">
        3 días
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="salida_pronosticada" value="female">
        5 días
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="salida_pronosticada" value="female">
        1 semana
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="salida_pronosticada" value="female">
        Otro
        <input type="text" name="salida_pronosticada_otro">
        días
        <br>
        <hr />
        <label>Stuff y cantidad</label>
        <div class="multi-field-wrapper">
            <div class="multi-fields">
                <div class="multi-field">
                    <input type="text" class="buscar_prod" name="input_referencia[]">
                    <input type="text" name="input_cantidad[]">
                    <button type="button" class="remove-field">
                        X
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="add-field">
                Add field
            </button>
            <input type="submit" name="guardar" value="Guardar" />
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
```

again... thanks for your time!

----EDITED----

Ok,.. I added 
`$(".buscar_prod").autocomplete("get_product_list.php", {width : 260, matchContains : true, selectFirst : false});` after

```
$('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
```

Now, autocomplete works for each dynamic input added, but it fires at the same time in the first input always. It doesn't mind if I focus the second, third, fourth, (etc) input, the first one also appears to get a focus and fires the autocomplete (see image below)

[image: multiple autocomplete]

Any help is very appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below changes

$('.multi-field:**first-child**', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();

in above line  , instead of first-child  write as  last-child  and try...
that is

$('.multi-field:**last-child**', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();

Thanks,

Bhimashankar ghathargi